# UWP app cannot find the USB device. Always getting null from UsbDevice.FromIdAsync()

Tags: c#, uwp, usb, printers

I tried to connect USB devices in uwp according to the instructions in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice?view=winrt-20348), but I couldn't connect to usb devices and always getting null from UsbDevice.FromIdAsync ().
I had seen may questions and answers regarding this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096871/uwp-app-cannot-find-connect-to-usb-device)   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901567/uwp-c-issue-with-aqs-and-usb-devices)

But nothing solved my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

these are the code snippet am trying. the same code snippet is working with .Net standard applications. But not working with UWP.

```
UsbDevice device = null;
        string HPVID = "1008";
        string pid = "9812";
        try
        {

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var aqsFilter = "System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:= System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True " + "AND System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.UsbVendorId:=" + HPVID +
                    "AND System.DeviceInterface.Winusb.UsbProductId:=" + pid;
                DeviceInformationCollection deviceInterface = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter);

                if (deviceInterface.Count > 0)
                {
                    device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInterface[0].Id);
                }

            }).Wait();
        }
```

Comment: have you add DeviceCapability  in the project manifest file like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L74).

Comment: Thank you @NicoZhu-MSFT . I have edited the Package.appxmanifest as per your comment and it is working for me.  I am trying to connect a printer via USB.  Really I want to know what actually <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/> means. and what value I need to give.  Am new to UWP and the USB connection, sorry if asked anything wrong

Comment: I have add the answer below, please check it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thank you for your help and the winusb communication is working fine. I have one more doubt, I need to communicate with the USB device via REST interface if the winusb interface is not available.  How can I implement USB communication through REST interface.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP app cannot find the USB device. Always getting null from UsbDevice.FromIdAsync()

Please check the package manifest file if add `DeviceCapability` capability, here is [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L74) that you could refer.

> Really I want to know what actually  means

We have [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-function) that explain the `Function` . And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-in-a-package-manifest) is document how to specify device capabilities in a package manifest. Here is [support list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/updating-the-app-manifest-with-usb-device-capabilities#supported-usb-device-classes) that you could refer.

> A string between 1 and 100 characters in length. Where appropriate, the string may begin with "classId:" | "winUsbId:" | "serviceId:" | "serviceId:" | "usage:" | "interfaceId:"