# WINUSB and UWP App: Can´t connect to my Device

Tags: c#, usb, windows-10-universal, winusb

I'm facing two different problems with my USB device that uses WINUSB ( Class 0xFF, Subclass 0x00 )

I have three different small apps, the UWP CustomUsbDeviceAccess from Microsoft samples modified to connect to my Custom USB Device, My UWP App i'm tryng to write, and a WPF sample program I wrote too. The three apps were working without problems, in my two computes, connecting to my WINUSB Custom Device, but in the middle of some windows/vs2017 upgrade, the two UWP Apps stopped working on both computers. The problems are different in both computers.

The first computer, with W10 Pro Fall Creators Update. The problem is, after calling this function:

```
this.device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(devId);
```

it always returns null. And if I try to run this:

```
var deviceAccessStatus = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(devId).CurrentStatus;
```

it raises the excpetion

> the system cannot find the file specified 0x80070002

The second computer, with W10 Home Insider Preview Build 17025.rs_prerelease.171020-1625, the problem here is that boths UWP App, CustomUsbDeviceAccess from Microsoft and my own UWP App, freeze entering this line:

```
var DeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceSelector);
```

These codes were working, i don´t undertand what´s wrong now. My USB device works in both computer with the small WPF Desktop App I wrote. I tested the same three apps with other similar USB commercial device I have in hand ( same class/subclass, winusb too), and I have the same results, so I discarded the problem is in my device or something wrong in the driver installation process.

I saw another user had a similar problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162862/cannot-create-usbdevice-from-deviceinformation-id), but sadly, didn't find the solution.

Comment: If you have solved your issue, you could post the answer below this case to convenient people who visit this thread laterand. you have no need put the solution in your case edit. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Yes, please post the answer because the question still shows up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the second computer: I re-installed the Windows 10 stable version ( Fall Creators ). In this second computer, my UWP App works and connect to my USB Device as expected.

In the first computer, my main wokstation, I think the problem is due to an error in the installation of the driver or in some permission. I would like to know where my error is; I imagine that this could be a problem in the installation in the clients that I would like to avoid